# Google remarketing retail pagetype other gives error

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

I'm having troubles implementing the google remarketing tags. It works great everywhere where we have a product but another page where it says pagetype="" it stils says nothing..

Remarketing tag assistent says:
Validate Products: Not valid
[image: Remarketing tag extension error]

This is my tag

```
<script>
var google_tag_params = {
   "ecomm_prodid": '',
   "ecomm_pagetype": "other",
   "ecomm_totalvalue": ""
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var google_conversion_id = xxxxxxxxx;
    var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
    var google_remarketing_only = true;
    /* ]]> */
</script>
```

but on another page where i have a product it's says it's fine and the tag looks like the image beneath it's fine. **So the problem has to do with the prodid being empty I guess.**

```
<script>
var google_tag_params = {
  'ecomm_pagetype': 'product',       //set the pagetype value
  'ecomm_prodid': ['woocommerce_gpf_5708'],      // sku
  'ecomm_totalvalue': '2800'      // total value
};
</script>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a definitive answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that ecomm_pagetype and ecomm_totalvalue has no value. Each parameter should have always some value or should not be displayed. For this page you should have only this

`var google_tag_params = {

   "ecomm_pagetype": "other"
};`

Now it is correct. But you will still have this error "Validate Products: Not valid" and this is O.K., because google tried to find the product in your merchant center, but it is just a page without a product, so the error could be ignored.

Answer (score -1):

You have to give us more information about PHP (I assume, that it's in PHP) code that put's this JavaScript to your website.

Without more information (what's template system use your website, how PHP code recognize product pages) there is no way to answer.

I can only recommend use Google Tag Assistant and try to find solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but infact this is not a php issue. So no need to post the source of that. I'm just not sure what i need to fill in when the pagetype is other. It feels like he needs a product after all. (I updated the question with a screenshot and some extra info)